# Bash / open a terminal with a command to run passed as an argument

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I created a script that starts all the apps I need for my day and assign them to the workspaces I want.

I'd like to know is there was a way to pass an argument to the terminal I open. The argument would be an **alias** that runs a massive source update of all the projects I'm working on.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
gnome-terminal start_rolls
```

Unfortunately, this only opens the terminal and the command is simply not run.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

Rolf

P.S.: the -e option does not work with aliases, it seems...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gnome-terminal --help-terminal-options` says:

> -e, --command                   Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal

Comment: with -e command you can pass arguments to any terminal emulator (xterm, gnome-terminal etc)

Comment: hmmm, I thought I commented this again yesterday, but it seems not...
my "start_rolls" command is an alias and is not executed with -e... I'm gonna check man pages again...

Comment: Rolf, if alias doesn't work for you, just wrap it into some bash script (`.sh`), give it an executable permission and invoke it instead of an alias.

Answer (score 2):

some combination of "`-e`", "`bash -c`", "`bash -i`" and your alias might help

Answer (score 0):

-e is going to be deprecated in future releases you should use something like this:

gnome-terminal -- bash -c "vim Main.java"

you can replace "vim Main.java" for whatever you want